# ManagedBean method is changing dataTable object

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, bootsfaces

I have a `<p:dataTable />` that lists "System Parameters" of a web page I'm working. One of that parameters is a mail server password, and it is encoded in Base64 in the DB. In the last column of the datatable, I have a button to edit that parameters, and when I click on it, a bootstrap modal is showed with the fields "name" and "value".

I have a ManagedBean with `@ViewScoped` scope, and a function that also recognizes if the parameter to edit is the mail server password, to have the value decoded. The method gets the object as an argument the datatable iteration object. My problem is that the first time I open the modal, the value of the object is correct, but in second time the object value changes and it generates an exception because the value is already decoded, and the value has a dot inside and it generates the error.

I don't understand why the datatable object value is changed when I never change it literally.

I'm using PrimeFaces, BootsFaces, JSF 2.2. This is my `<p:dataTable />`:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{parameterBean.listParameter}" var="p" 
                         paginator="true" rows="10" 
                         reflow="true" id="tblParameter" 
                         emptyMessage="No data available.">
    <!-- Some columns -->

    <p:column headerText="Options">
        <b:commandButton value="Edit" icon="edit" look="info" 
                         ajax="true" update="parametroForm" 
                         onclick="ajax:parameterBean.editParameter(p)" 
                         oncomplete="$('#parameterModal').modal('show');" />
</p:dataTable>
```

And this is my bean method:

```
public void editParameter(TblParameter p) {
   System.out.println("ENCODE: " + p.getVlrParameter());
    this.param = new TblParameter(); //- This is an object in the bean to access it from modal form.

    try {
        setParam(p);

        if (getParam().getIdParameter().equals(new Long(4))) {//- Validate if is the server mail password.
            byte[] clv64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(p.getVlrParameter().getBytes());
            getParam().setVlrParameter(new String(clv64));
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally, as I said when I open for first time the modal, the output printed is this:

```
ENCODE: MTIzLjQ1Ng==
```

But in second time, it shows:

```
ENCODE: 123.456
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2e
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
at com.abcpagos.otis.beans.admin.ParametroBean.editarParametro(ParametroBean.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)...
```

If someone could please give me an explanation of this behavior, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Although this has little to do with your question: from a security point of view, never decode a password. Always use the encoded version. Some hackers have tools scanning the memory for the password. As long as they can only see the encoded version, little harm is done. Plus, you should adopt a one-way encryption. There shouldn't be a way to guess the unencrypted password from a copy of the encrypted password table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions; I decided to decode the password in case the user wants to keep the same password but adding some chars, for example if the password is `123.456` and the user now wants `123.45677`. But I'm thinking it's better to make that the user writes the password complete always it wants to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you do change the parameter accidentially. Have a look at these lines:

```
byte[] clv64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(p.getVlrParameter().getBytes());
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
getParam().setVlrParameter(new String(clv64));
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the second time you try to decode the parameter that's already stored in plain text.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit confused, but I still don't understand, because the `p` object is not the same as the one associated with `getParam()` method. In my bean I have a `private TblParameter param;` declared, and I'm using it to show data in the modal form (the data that comes in the dataTable object), so in theory I'm not overriting the dataTable object because I only use it to get values, am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that `p.getVlrParameter()` and `getParam()` are different objects? I can't judge that from that little source code you showed us. However, it often happens that developers copy a variable without considering that variables are just references (or pointers) to memory locations. I guess that's what happening here, too. Usually, I track down this kind of errors by inspecting the variables in the Eclipse debugger. In the debugger window, it shows not only the value, but also an `id`. This `id` is (kind of) a pointer to the memory location. Do your variable share a common `id`?

Comment: BTW, I suppose the same trick works with the other IDEs, too.

Comment: I see, maybe it's the object references. I will give a try to debug the code. Thank you.